# After updating Xamarin and Xcode, failing to run app on iOS device

Tags: xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I recently updated Xcode and Xamarin and when I deploy my project to my simulator on iOS it works well. But when I however try to use my phone that has been working succesfully for many months now it does not work and I get this error in the log:

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: /Users/Carlos/Projects/Myproject/iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/build-iphone8.1-9.3.2/ibtool-link/LaunchScreen.storyboardc/02J-Ip-oVM-view-Ze4-5b-2t2.nib does not exist`

My bundle identifier matches my provisioning profile that I have made on apple.

I have tried to delete the obj and bin folders in the projectmap/mainmap (not the obj and bin-folders inside the iOS folder) but without any success. I have also rebuild the project and cleaned it but the problem still remains.

When I create a brand new project however it works. So it seems to be a problem with old projects only.

In the map on my old project I cannot even find "ibtool-link" and if I check the newly made project I just made i can see it there and other maps as well. Can I solve it by copying them over? Or is there a better solution?

Any ideas what it might be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try the suggestions (I saw at least 2 different ones) in [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/69225/system-io-filenotfoundexception-launchscreen-nib-does-not-exist) post which are:

> simply right click on the xib and open it in IB. I then turn around and close it in IB and that gets me past the error.

And

> make sure 'Main Interface' empty in info.plist.
>   Remove Bin and Obj folder.

Also you might try deleting the build cache on your mac by going to `/Users/<Your User Account Name>/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/` and then delete the folder that is the same name as your solution (there might be 2, one with `iOS` in the name, delete both). This will get recreated when you rebuild your solution.

Comment: Solved the problem :) Thanks a ton

Comment: @CarlosRodrigez Nice! No problem